# Error with spring-security while migrating from 4.0.2 to 6.1.3

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security

I have a spring web application that run on a tomcat (previously a tomcat 7 and now on a tomcat 10 since it's the one that handle the javax to jakarta namespace migration).

The compilation work fine but when running the server I have this error (nothing in the cut stacktace is winthin my packages) :

```
14-Sep-2023 10:09:18.929 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
14-Sep-2023 10:09:18.940 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
14-Sep-2023 10:09:37.555 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
        ...
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
        ...
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
        ... 58 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.http.AuthorizationFilterParser$RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManagerFactory#0' while setting constructor argument
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
        ...
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
        ... 72 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.http.AuthorizationFilterParser$RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManagerFactory#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#27e685a3' of type [org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionAuthorizationManager] while setting bean property 'requestMatcherMap' with key [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servlet.util.matcher.MvcRequestMatcher]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodNames=null; destroyMethodNames=null]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBeanValue(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:421)
        ...
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
        ... 84 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#27e685a3': Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionAuthorizationManager]: Constructor threw exception
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:326)
        ...
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBeanValue(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:407)
        ... 100 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionAuthorizationManager]: Constructor threw exception
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:110)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:323)
        ... 106 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expressionString cannot be empty
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:294)
        ...
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211)
        ... 108 more
14-Sep-2023 10:09:37.646 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

From what I've seen on the web it seem's likely that this is an issue in the security.xml file but nothing I've tried seems to solve the issue and I don't manage to understand the root of the error with the stacktrace.
Here is my security.xml file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-6.1.xsd">

    <!-- Activating the security component Autowire -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.package.security"/>

    <!-- Do not secure static ressources -->
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/*"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/ressources/**"/>

    <security:http entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
        <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/ihm/**"/>
    </security:http>

    <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" autowire="byName"
          class="my.package.security.MyAppAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="authenticationProvider" autowire="byName" class="my.package.security.MyAppAuthenticationProvider"
          autowire-candidate="true"/>

    <bean id="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter" autowire="byName"
          class="my.package.security.MyAppAuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter"/>

    <bean id="mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector"/>
</beans>
```

The MyAppAuthenticationEntryPoint file :

```java
package my.package.security;

import java.io.IOException;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;

public class MyAppAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

The MyAppAuthenticationProvider file :

```java
package my.package.security;

import java.util.List;

import lombok.Setter;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import my.package.UserIHM;

@Component
public class MyAppAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String identifiantActiveDirectory = authentication.getName();
        ...
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, authentication.getAuthorities());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The RedacAuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter file :

```java
package my.package.security;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;

import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import lombok.Setter;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;


public class MyAppAuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter extends GenericFilterBean implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    @Setter
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(true);
        Authentication authentication = (Authentication) session.getAttribute(SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_AUTHENTICATION);
        if (authentication == null) {
            Principal principal = httpRequest.getUserPrincipal();
            if (principal == null) {
                ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "User not authentified");
                return;
            }
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = resolveGrantedAuthorities(httpRequest);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, null, authorities);
            token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails((HttpServletRequest) request));
            try {
                authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
            } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
                ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, principal.getName());
                return;
            }
            session.setAttribute("userToken", authentication);
        }
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        chain.doFilter(httpRequest, response);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> resolveGrantedAuthorities(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {

        ...

        return authorities;
    }
}
```

The pom.xml of the project :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>myapp-ihm</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Web dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Java Standard Tag Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <!-- FilterChain for UTF-8 force-encoding -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <!-- FilterChain proxy for security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Bootstraps the root web application context before servlet initialization -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Beans in these files will makeup the configuration of the root web
        application context -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:my/app/config.xml <!-- I know that this config file is fine since there are other part of the app that run fine with it -->
            /WEB-INF/context/security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>prod-jndi</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ihm</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/context/ihm.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Maps all URLs starting with /ihm to the 'ihm' servlet. -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ihm</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ihm/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Lot of security roles -->
    <security-role>
        <role-name>APP-SEC-ROLE-1</role-name>
    </security-role>
    ...

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <url-pattern>/ihm/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <!-- Use BASIC security -->
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```